# Xamarin Android media app showing 2 instances in Android Auto console

Tags: xamarin, android-mediaplayer, android-auto

I am working on a Xamarin Android media app and trying to add support for Android Auto. I have followed the Android Auto guidelines and best practices and have properly configured my app for Android Auto. However, when I test my app on the Android Auto Development Desktop Head Unit (DHU), I see two instances of my app: one for the regular mobile app and another for the Android Auto app.

Because of this, when I play audio from my mobile app, it does not play the audio in the Android Auto app. I am not sure what I am missing here. When I play another instance app from Android auto, Its playing the audio with the expected UI but mobile app & Android auto apps were not in sync with each other?

I added below piece of code in the manifest, automotive_app_desc.xml file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/`>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="media"/>
</automotiveApp>
```

Am I missing anything here?